# Как запустить функцию внутри класса?

Tags: python

```
 class test:
        def A(self):
            name = 'testfunc'
            name = self.name()
            print(name)
        def testfunc(self):
            return 'ok'
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно так, но это плохой путь, лучше уж eval:  

    name= self.__dict__[name]()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска функции testfunc c класса нужно использовать

```
self.testfunc()
```

Если имя функции определяется динамически то тогда

```
name = 'testfunc'
getattr(self, name)()
```

Comment: И еще один вопрос, у меня есть главный скрипт, в него я подключаю этот класс как модуль и мне приходится каждый раз при подключении нового модуля указывать import locale
Можно указать его в главном скрипте? Я указываю, а если удалить с модуля то модуль выбивает ошибку....